# Keep getting Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined error in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have an app that I have created. 
The app up until now has been able to login existing users and register new users using the firebase console.

I clicked on firebase Assistant in an attempt to troubleshoot a different error and saw that the dependencies were not set up correctly (I really thought they were) so I clicked to set them up, and my app is now broken.

With firebase, it says to add the dependency to the gradle file. 
I have followed the documentation from Firebase and when I first created the app a few months ago, everything worked. But now for some reason I cannot register users when the dependency is present.

The app also force stops when include the analytics dependency.

The code I have attached is the only code my app will run on (as i mentioned, when I ad in the necessary dependencies I get the error mentioned in the title)

This is due in a day and so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.securityapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Where would this go @Sam

Comment: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
   }
}` here

Comment: So Ive added this here and the app opens only if  'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1' and 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0' are not present. When I add these dependencies, the app wont even open. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding and I have also tried making a completely new project but nothing seems to be working

Comment: in your manifest file the versions you are using is outdated.. can you try updating it to the latest version?

Comment: Sorry for being so inexperienced, but how would I do this?

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'` this line.. in your manifest.. change it to latest `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'`. You can also do that by going to manifest file, and the outdated version will be highlighed in the goldish color.. hover over the dependencies you need to change and press Alt + Enter and it will automatically open the dialog suggesting you the latest version.

Comment: I am no longer able to open my project. When I open android studio it says fatal error initializing plugin gradle gui :( I have tried restarting my computer but still getting the error

Comment: @Sam I was able to get my app open again. Anytime I have com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0 or com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1 included in my app, it breaks it

Comment: As far as the dependencies are concerned, it seems to look alright.. can you upload the logcat? what exactly the error says

Comment: So after crashing I uninstalled and reinstalled android studio and got rid of everything and just made a new project and everything seems to be working now! Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem, Cheers